# How to use LinkedHashMap collection in Groovy Script - SoapUI?

Tags: java, groovy, collections, soapui

I'm using **Groovy Script** step in the **SoapUI** test suite. In the script, I'm trying to pass a linkedhashmap to the method along with other two strings parameters.

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> suitesInfo = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
                        suitesInfo.put(request_1,context.testCase.getPropertyValue(request_1 + "_RESPONSE_STATUS"))
                        suitesInfo.put(request_2,context.testCase.getPropertyValue(request_2 + "_RESPONSE_STATUS"))
                        suitesInfo.put(request_3,context.testCase.getPropertyValue(request_3 + "_RESPONSE_STATUS"))

String tSuiteName = sheetName
String tcID = context.testCase.getPropertyValue("TC_ID")

//Pass the tcID, tSuiteName and Map to the method writeTestSuiteStatusInExcel()
writeTestsuiteStatusInExcel(tSuiteName,tcID,suitesInfo);
```

While executing this script, I'm getting the error message like this.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script6.writeTestsuiteStatusInExcel() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [A, 1234567, [PUT Request:PASS, GET Request:PASS, ...]] Possible solutions: writeTestSuiteStatusInExcel(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap) error at line: 133
```

So what is the mistake that I have done here, I don't understand. Anyone correct my script to achieve my task.

Thanks

Comment: Provide the complete definition of the writeTestsuiteStatusInExcel(), parameters you are passing to this method may not of same type as of definition.

Comment: What version of Groovy is this? A few recent ones had bugs regarding this resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake in method name:

```
writeTestsuiteStatusInExcel(tSuiteName,tcID,suitesInfo)
```

should be

```
writeTestSuiteStatusInExcel(tSuiteName,tcID,suitesInfo)
```